# Json conversion

Tags: java, android, json

i want to create a Json like this

```
     [{"sID":"221","mID":"0"},
     {"sID":"222","mID":"11"},
     {"sID":"223","mID":"11"}]
```

i have tried below code but that create Json just only for one line

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject manJson = new JSONObject();
    manJson.put("sID", "23");
    manJson.put("mID", "111");
    json.put("",manJson);
```

this above code create Json like this

```
  {"":{"sID":"23","mID":"111"}}
```

Please let me know about the changes required in that Java code thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

//Add 1st JSONObject to JSONArray
JSONObject jsonObjone = new JSONObject();    
jsonObjone.put("sID", "221");
jsonObjone.put("mID","0");
jsonArray.put(jsonObjone.toString();

//Add 2nd JSONObject to JSONArray
JSONObject jsonObjtwo = new JSONObject();    
jsonObjtwo.put("sID", "222");
jsonObjtwo.put("mID","11");
jsonArray.put(jsonObjtwo.toString());

//Add 3rd JSONObject to JSONArray
JSONObject jsonObjthrd = new JSONObject();    
jsonObjthrd.put("sID", "223");
jsonObjthrd.put("mID","11");
jsonArray.put(jsonObjthrd.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply; but it gives error "The method toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject" at jsonArray.push(jsonObj. _toJSONString()_);

Comment: O yes done thank You very Much Imran Saved alot of my time :-) stay blessed buddy.

Comment: why you are converting jsonarray to JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

Use `toJSONArray()` method on `manjson`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [jackson library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) it makes things very easy. To use it you would have an object like this...

```
class Ids {

     private int Sid;
     private int Mid;

     public setSid(int Sid) {
         this.Sid = Sid;
     }

     public setMid(int Mid) {
         this.Mid = Mid;
     }

     public getSid() {
         return Sid;
     }

     public getMid() {
         return Mid;
     }
}
```

Then you can use the objectMapper from the library to go from an array that you have in memory to a json String like so

```
      Ids[] idsArray = new Ids[2];
      //add ids object to array
      String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(idsArray);
```

Of course doing it this way depends on how your ids are stored but for me it generally makes my code a lot cleaner and the Jackson Library is pretty good performance wise.